# Different URL's using the same action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

what i need, is routing for

```
resources :posts
```

but considering every post object has different category (category is a column in the database, not referenced object!), categories are kept in `Page::CATEGORIES`. bottom line, i need e.g. `'www.example.com/posts/admin_posts'` route into `post/index action`, but with parameter `'admin_posts'` so i can use it in the scope. i hope i made myself clear:)
I DON'T want any more actions, and definitely dont want to define every route separately, they all should come from `Page::CATEGORIES`.
Any idea how to do it?

EDIT

I'm editing this question since it is not really clear

having a model `Post`, with column category and all categories stored in `Post::CATEGORIES`, my goal is to have route, for every category, but, every route taking it into the same old index action.

```
def index
    @posts = Post.by_category(category)
end
```

now, category here, is an argument for the scope, which will allow me to get only those Posts, which are specified in the route. Eg posts/stupid_posts would make `category = "stupid_posts"`, and `@posts` only stupid_posts.
really hope its better now

Comment: Please show us what you tried (and edit your question to make it more clear)

Comment: i havent tried anything, since i dont have any idea how to do it. what is unclear?

Comment: Well, regarding the close vote requests... it seems to be yes

Comment: i asked WHAT is not clear, not if you are sure about it:)

Comment: Have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. From there if you're still having issues with your routes you may have a better way to formulate your question (we don't know what you're trying to ask!)

Section 1.2 should be relevant to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a route like this:

```
get '/posts/:category', to: 'posts#index',
  constraints: { category: Regexp.new(Post::CATEGORIES.join('|')) }
```

Then in `index` you can get the category via `params[:category]`:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.by_category(params[:category])
end
```

Comment: this looks interesting, gonna give it a try

Comment: first: should this 'get 'posts..' be inside of resources block?, second: how the example url is gonna look? posts/stupid_posts or posts/:stupid_posts?

Comment: No this is a separate route that should be above the resources block. The URL will be `posts/stupid_posts`.

Comment: ok, got it, but now i'm unable to use show action since posts/1 or posts/awesome_post is taking me to the index action...

Comment: I edited my answer. Does `posts/1` go to the show action with this?

Comment: no it works, only one issue now, how to replace category: /stupid_post|awesome_post/ with my Post::CATEGORIES constant?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a punt on this question. But I highly recommend you look at the [rails routing section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Since you have categories in a constant `Page::CATEGORIES`, you can write a helper for this. Here's a quick and dirty way for the sake of brevity:

```
- Page::CATEGORIES.each do |cat|
  = link_to cat, posts_path(category: cat)
```

Loop over the page categories and supply them to the params hash. Then, in the controller method that looks up the posts, you will have access to `params[:category]`. Use it to query for the relevant posts.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually do it the other way around. From the hierarchy point of view, posts belong to category, and not category belongs to posts (regardless of how you model it in the database), so I would use the following routes:

```
scope ":category" do
  resources :posts, as: :category_posts
end
```

This will route to `posts` controller, and will have `params[:category]` available on each request.

Inside the controller I would check if params[:category] actually exists and return 404 if it doesn't.